# How to load MainActivity.java from server?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app in which the code is in MainActivity.java (locally) but I would like know how can I load MainActivity.java externally?

Example: Save the MainActivity.java on my web server. When the app loads, it get MainActivity.java from my server rather than locally?

I've been searching the web and Stack Overflow but haven't had any luck.

Comment: What business requirement prompted you for this technical design? I think you are on wrong thought path.

Comment: Hi Nambari, the app contains sensitive information and with tools available online anybody can decompile app and get sourcecode. So, just looking at ways to prevent this from happening.

Comment: If it has sensitive information, you better think about 'encryption' or server/client(app) approach. You suggested approach simply not supported by underlying platform.

Comment: Everything is compiled in to the APK before you even start the app.  Whatever sensitive information such as security keys must be downloaded after you run the app and *not saved on the device at all*.  If you want more security, you can look in to tools like DexGuard. DexGuard will *not* prevent people from seeing everything though. Just makes it harder. https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The idea of an app is that the code run on the device is local.  Not running downloaded code is part of the design.  Can you imagine what a security nightmare it would be to run non-sandboxed code downloaded from a server at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

i too really want to load a method from server , by which I can make changes in the method without upda

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).